# Liminf and limsup of $A_n = \{m/n: m \in \mathbb N\}$

Tags: probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf

I'm doing some exercises on Chapter 1 of Resnick's *A Probability Path* and got confused in this question:

> Suppose $A_n = \{m/n: m \in \mathbb N\}, n \in\mathbb N$,
>   where $\mathbb N$ are non-negative integers, what are
>   $\liminf A_n$ and $\limsup A_n$?

I understand both definition of $\liminf A_n$ and $\limsup A_n$ are:

$$\liminf A_n = \bigcup_{n\ge 1}\bigcap_{k\ge n}A_k\qquad\limsup A_n = \bigcap_{n\ge 1}\bigcup_{k\ge n}A_k$$

I tried to do $\liminf$ but I've got null set just by observation which is of course not recommended when answering mathematical questions.

What confuses me here is $m$ in a way that I don't know how to use this in a sequence since sequences should have a "pattern going somewhere" as $n$ goes to $\infty$. Surely, I can't treat $m$ as something that approaches some integer (i.e. m shouldn't be treated as increasing or decreasing).

Comment: "by observation which is of course not recommended when answering mathematical questions." Hmmm, "observation" is fine but you are right, it is recommended to complete it by proofs. And to do that, you have one and only tool at your disposal, which is the definition of the objects involved. Here, to determine the liminf, you want those $x$ such that $x\in A_n$ for every $n$ large enough... So, is it possible that there exists $N$ such that, for every $n\geqslant N$ there exists $m$ such that $x=m/n$? This would mean that $x=m_0/n_0$ for some given $(m_0,n_0)$, then ...

Comment: ... can you exhibit a large $n$ such that $x=m/n$ is impossible? Hint: *prime numbers* are cool...

Comment: (Please use `\limsup` and `\liminf` and `\in`.)

Comment: I'm not sure If I can follow your hint @Did :(.

$x = m / n$ is only impossible when $n = 0$, right?

Answer (score 4):

$A_n = \{ \frac{m}{n} ,m \in \mathbb{N}\}$

$\limsup A_n  = \{ x | x \in A_n $ for infinitely many $n\}$.

$\liminf A_n = \{ x | x \notin A_n $ only for finitely many $n\}$.

It is clear that no irrational numbers belong to $A_n$ for any $n$. So it is enough for us to consider rational numbers.

$x \in A_n \iff xn=m$ for some $m  \in \mathbb{N}$.

If we write $x=\frac{p}{q}$ in lowest form (It's possible that $q=1$), then $xn=m$ for some $m$ if and only if $n | q$.  That is, $x \in A_{kq} \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$, since $\frac{p(kq)}{q} = pk \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, every rational number $x$, $x \in \limsup A_n$.This shows that $\limsup A_n = \mathbb{Q}$.

If $x \in \liminf A_n$, then there is some natural number $N$ such that $x \in A_n$ if $n > N$. Now, we have that $\frac{p(N+1)}{q}$ is an integer, and $\frac{p(N+2)}{q}$ is an integer. Subtracting, we have that $\frac{p}{q}$ is an  integer,which happens only when $x$ is an integer itself. On the other hand, of course an integer is in $A_n$ for every $n$ . Hence, it follows that $\liminf A_n = \mathbb{N}$.

---

I'm keeping my explanation on, since you are attempting to understand it.

> $\limsup A_n  =\displaystyle\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k \geq n} A_k$.
>
> $\liminf A_n  =\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k \geq n} A_k$.

$\forall i \in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q }$, $i \notin A_n \ \forall n$, so $i \notin \limsup A_n,i \notin \liminf A_n$.

Let $x=\frac{p}{q}$. Then, $x (kq) = \frac{p(kq)}{q} = pk \in \mathbb{N}$, so $x \in A_{kq} \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now, given  $m \in \mathbb{N}$,there is some $k$ such that $kq > m$. So, for all $m$, $x \in \bigcup_{l \geq m} A_l$, taking $l=kq$. Since the above applies for all $m$, it follows that $x \in \displaystyle\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \bigcup_{l \geq m} A_l = \limsup A_m$. Since $x$ was a rational number, and we already showed that irrationals can't be part of $A_n$, it follows that $\limsup A_n = \mathbb{Q}$.

The other way, suppose that $x = \frac{p}{q} \in \liminf A_n  =\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k \geq n} A_k$. This means that $x \in \bigcap_{k \geq n} A_k$ for some natural number $N$. This means, that $x(N+2)=\frac{p(N+2)}{q}$ and $x(N+1)=\frac{p(N+1)}{q}$ are both integers. By subtraction, we get that $\frac{p}{q}$ is also a natural number.  But then, $x$ itself is a natural number. So every number in the $\liminf$ is a natural number.

On the other hand, if we have a natural number $q$, then $q \in A_n$ for all $n$, because taking $m= qn$, we see that $q = \frac{qn}{n}$, so $q \in A_n$. Since this applies for all $n$, certainly $q \in \bigcap_{n \geq 1} A_n$, and hence $q \in \displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k \geq n} A_k$. Thus, all natural numbers are in the $\liminf$.

Thus, $\liminf A_n= \mathbb{N}$. I hope this was a clearer solution than the previous one.

Comment: While I can follow this solution, I'm wondering if it is possible to do this using the definition of $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ stated I stated above?

Comment: I can do  something. I can prove that your definition and my definition are the same. Should I do that, or should I actually rewrite the proof using your definition? (I can even do both, if you like)

Comment: Just using my definition would work. I'm also trying to put your reasoning as hint to a solution using my given definition but still confused. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: The problem with the solution using my definition is that I don't know how to use $m$ s.t. $m \epsilon \mathbb N$.